# Check Objective-C String for specific characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, illegal-characters

For an app I'm working on, I need to check if a text field contains only the letters A, T, C, or G. Furthermore, I would like to make specialized error messages for any other inputed characters. ex) "Don't put in spaces." or "The letter b isn't an accepted value." I have read a couple other posts like this, but they are alphanumeric, I only want specified characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach for you, far from unique:

`NString` has methods to find substrings, represented as an `NSRange` of location & offset, made up from characters in a given `NSCharacterSet`.

The set of what should be in the string:

```
NSCharacterSet *ATCG = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ATCG"];
```

And the set of what shouldn't:

```
NSCharacterSet *invalidChars = [ATCG invertedSet];
```

You can now search for any range of characters consisting of `invalidChars`:

```
NSString *target; // the string you wish to check
NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, target.length); // search the whole string
NSRange foundRange = [target rangeOfCharacterFromSet:invalidChars
                                             options:0 // look in docs for other possible values
                                               range:searchRange];
```

If there are no invalid characters then `foundRange.location` will be equal to `NSNotFound`, otherwise you change examine the range of characters in `foundRange` and produce your specialised error messages.

You repeat the process, updating `searchRange` based on `foundRange`, to find all the runs of invalid characters.

You could accumulate the found invalid characters into a set (maybe `NSMutableSet`) and produce the error messages at the end.

You can also use regular expressions, see `NSRegularExpressions`.

Etc. HTH

**Addendum**

There is a really simple way to address this, but I did not give it as the letters you give suggest to me you may be dealing with very long strings and using provided methods as above may be a worthwhile win. However on second thoughts after your comment maybe I should include it:

```
NSString *target; // the string you wish to check
NSUInteger length = target.length; // number of characters
BOOL foundInvalidCharacter = NO;   // set in the loop if there is an invalid char

for(NSUInteger ix = 0; ix < length; ix++)
{
   unichar nextChar = [target characterAtIndex:ix]; // get the next character

   switch (nextChar)
   {
      case 'A':
      case 'C':
      case 'G':
      case 'T':
         // character is valid - skip
         break;

      default:
         // character is invalid
         // produce error message, the character 'nextChar' at index 'ix' is invalid
         // record you've found an error
         foundInvalidCharacter = YES;
   }
}

// test foundInvalidCharacter and proceed based on it
```

HTH

Comment: How do I examine a range of characters? As you can tell, I'm still trying to learn all this objective-C stuff, theres a lot of it.

Comment: Again many ways, but at the simplest level there is the `characterAtIndex:` method on `NSString` - the range gives you the starting index and the length so a simple loop can examine each character in turn. There are methods to give you the range as an `NSString` as well, etc. Read the `NSString`, and maybe the `NSMutableSet`, doc pages.

Answer (score 2):

Use NSRegulareExpression like this.

```
NSString *str = @"your input string";
NSRegularExpression *regEx = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"A|T|C|G" options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [regEx matchesInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *result in matches) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [str substringWithRange:result.range]);
}
```

Also for the options parameter you have to look in the documentation to pick one that fits.

Comment: What exactly is the for loop doing?

Comment: The method above returns all matches in the string so you have to loop them and extract each match separately.

Comment: Also i noticed i did not supply a pattern! If you want to match A, T, C or G use @"A|T|C|G" as pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the NSRegularExpression class reference.

Visit: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html